# Java Sesiones en Servlet y JSP Great Number game

Tags: java, jsp

No logro solucionar mi problema. Tengo que crea una web dinámica en el metodo "doPost" del juego Great number, Indicando de un numero entre el 1 al 100, Que este muestre too low, too high y You did en caso de que logre adivinar el numero que genero la pagina de forma random. No encuentro mi error y al momento de ejecutar y enviar el numero me retorna con "Served at: /GreatNumberGame" GreatNumberGame es el nombre del proyecto.

Controlador servlet con sesion (doPost) El nombre de la clase es "GreatNumber"

```
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    //doGet(request, response);
    HttpSession session = request.getSession();
    
    int numS=Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("number"));
    
    String number = request.getParameter("numberoElegido");
    int num = Integer.parseInt(number);

    int random = (int) (1 + Math.random() * 100);
    
    if(num>numS) {
        session.setAttribute("number", random);
        session.setAttribute("mensaje", "Too low");
        response.sendRedirect("index.jsp");
    }
    else if(num<numS){
        session.setAttribute("number", random);
        session.setAttribute("mensaje", "Too High");
        response.sendRedirect("index.jsp");
    }else if(num == numS){
        session.setAttribute("number", random);
        session.setAttribute("mensaje", "You did");
        response.sendRedirect("index.jsp");
    }
    else {
        response.sendRedirect("index.jsp");
    }
    
    RequestDispatcher view = request.getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp");
    view.forward(request, response);
    
    response.sendRedirect("/index");
}
```

Aqui esta el JSP que lo tengo nombrado como index.jsp

```
    <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <link href="estilo" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Great Number</title>  
</head>
<body style="background: #e7e7e7">

<%
    String message=(String)session.getAttribute("message");
%>
 
<center>

<h1 style = "font-family:courier,arial,helvética;">Welcome to the Great Number Game!</h1>
<h2 style = "font-family:courier,arial,helvética;">I am thinking of a number berween 1 and 100 <br> Take a guess!</h2>

<form action="GreatNumber" methods="post">

   <input type="text" name="number">    
   <input type = "submit" value = "submit" >  
   <br></br>
   
    <%= message %>

</form>
<br></br>
<form action="index.jsp" method="post">
    <input type = "submit" value = "Obtener nuevo numero">
</form>
</center>

</body>
</html>
```

`

Answer (score 2):

Problema soluciondo.
Servlet

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        HttpSession sesion = request.getSession();
        int numeroIngresado=Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("number"));
        int numeroAleatorio = (int) (1 + Math.random() * 100);
        
        if(numeroIngresado>numeroAleatorio) {
            sesion.setAttribute("number", numeroAleatorio);
            sesion.setAttribute("message", "Too High");
        }
        else if(numeroIngresado<numeroAleatorio){
            sesion.setAttribute("number", numeroAleatorio);
            sesion.setAttribute("message", "Too Low");
        }else if(numeroIngresado == numeroAleatorio){
            sesion.setAttribute("number", numeroAleatorio);
            sesion.setAttribute("message", "You did");
        }
        RequestDispatcher view = request.getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp");
        view.forward(request, response);
    }

}
```

Index.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@page session="true"%>  

<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <link href="estilo" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Great Number</title>  
</head>
<body style="background: #e7e7e7">

<%
    HttpSession sesion=request.getSession();
    String message=(String)sesion.getAttribute("message");
%>
 
<center>

<h1 style = "font-family:courier,arial,helvética;">Welcome to the Great Number Game!</h1>
<h2 style = "font-family:courier,arial,helvética;">I am thinking of a number berween 1 and 100 <br> Take a guess!</h2>

<form action="GreatNumber" method="POST">

   <input type="text" name="number">    
   <input type = "submit" value = "submit">  
   <br></br>
 <h1 style="color: red; border: red 5px dotted;"><%= message %></h1>  
    

</form>
<br></br>
<form action="index.jsp" method="POST">
    <input type = "submit" value = "Obtener nuevo numero">
</form>
</center>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Qué bien! Como sugerencia, para que tu solución también le sirva a otros en el futuro, podrías comentar brevemente qué cambiaste para que se resolviera